# Find number of unused disk bays on a dell server running windows or ESXi

Tags: hard-drive, dell, drac

I have a project kicking off to implement a new backup solution across our estate of 1500 physical servers. One of the bits of info I need to get is how many drive slots are free on each server (so we can add required disk or plan to purchase a MD device where the chassis is full already). FYI, we'll backup to local disk, dedupe and aux to Datacenters)
Is there any racadm commands or a script I could run to get this info?
We run a range of R610 - R630 and R710-730's across the estate with a combination of drives and chassis configurations.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the Dell support site to see what the configuration of the shipped server was by inputting the service tag (get the service tag remotely `wmic bios get serialnumber` )
2. Connect to the out of band management controller (iDrac)
3. Run racadm hwinventory
4. Use Open Manage Server administrator
5. talk to the pci bus `lspci` and talk to the bios `dimidecode`

in the end it will be a mixture of knowing what hardware you have and with what options (daughter cards, mezzanines, SAS expander) then simply listing the physical disks `pvs` or `wmic diskdrive list brief` 
R730's can hold up to 8 as a max by default and up to 16 in the drive bay **and** inside the chassis.

Comment: With 1500 servers going to the dell site for each won't be an option. I have all the data from OME (Service tags, lists of disks) but the issue is knowing how many bays are in each server. They have been purchased with mixes of 2.5 and 3.5" disks for example so difficult to work out if there are any free bays.

Comment: yeah, they've vertical and horizon options and some expansion options, I though OME would give you an exportable inventory - does it not list the bays?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
[root@localhost ~]# racadm hwinventory

[InstanceID: Enclosure.Internal.0-1:NonRAID.Integrated.1-1]
Device Type = Enclosure
ProductName = BP14G+EXP 0:1
TempProbeCount = 0
FanCount = 0
PSUCount = 0
EMMCount = 0
SlotCount = 12
```